# Is it possible hide any input fields of a form during a cypress test?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

Ok, I have a form with several inputs in it. The validation of the inputs happens after the submit event. I would like to test each field on isolated tests, but I wouldn't like to fill all other fields in each isolated test to do that validation.

[image]

What I would like it's a way to hide the fields that I'm not testing in each isolated test.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to keep test file short, then what about setting default values for all inputs in beforeEach(), and setting specific values in it()

Comment: Oh, great! It has worked for almost 100% of tests. In each "it block test" I only need clear the field that I'm testing. It only doesn't work when I need to test a radio input cause it cannot be cleared through the cypress.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding will not help, you would have to remove

```js
cy.get('element-to-be-removed').then($el => $el[0].remove)
```

But this feels like a bad really idea. If your validation code references the element, it will throw an error.

Hiding avoids that problem, but the validation code will still look for a value in the hidden element.

So what really is the problem with filling in all the fields except for the one you are testing?

Comment: Oh, I think the real problem is that my test file will be too big. I have 15 inputs in my form. In each isolated test of the fifteen ones, I'll need to fill fourteen ones that I'm not really testing. It would be 210 lines unnecessary.

Comment: You can use a data-driven approach.

Comment: Put all the element names in an array then loop through the array testing each element. That cuts down the code needed. Maybe give that a go?